# How do I install Enchant on Anaconda Windows via a tar.gz download?

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda, gzip

Thanks for reading: please forgive how rubbish I am at dealing with installations.

I want to install Enchant on Windows in my Anaconda Python distribution.

It is available from this website: http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/download.html

There is a `.gz` file and a `.exe` file.

I am not able to use the .exe as the inbuilt installer does not detect the correct python distribution on my computer (I have separate installs of 2.7/3.5/Anaconda 4.2).

I download the file `enchant-1.6.0.tar.gz`to my downloads folder.

Now: what exactly do I do now to install it in Windows into my Anaconda Python distribution? I tried unzipping it but there are no executables within it. Do I have to do something via CMD or Anacaonda Command Prompt?

Any help much appreciated.

Edit: To be clear, I have already installed Pyenchant. It is enchant that I cannot install.

Edit: There are a ton of files within the zip download including three different configure files, install-sh (for Linux?). How do I use what is there either within CMD or otherwise?

Edit: Looks like Enchant only works on 64 bit Python. Could this be why the auto exe installer does not detect my Anaconda distribution, or do I have to tell it where to look?

Comment: `pip install pyenchant` is generally a good way, making sure that you use the `pip` from the Anaconda installation. Does it require compilation of C/C++ sources?

Comment: My apologies. I had listed the incorrect gz file. It is the `enchant-1.6.0...` that I want to install. I have already installed `pyenchant` within anaconda as you suggest. Whenever I run anything I get the error: `ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.`

Comment: I'd recommend downloading the wheel file and installing it with pip. Again, make sure that you use the proper pip.

Comment: No - I have installed everything that it is possible to install with pip, with pip (`conda list` shows Pyenchant right where it should be). Pyenchant is just a Python wrapper for the C module Enchant. The problem is not with Pyenchant.

Even if you install Pyenchant with pip, if you don't have enchant installed separately it won't work. 

My question is not about Pyenchat in Python, rather, how you install Enchant on Widnows.

Comment: In fact: irrespective of how to work the .gz file, my research has shown that Enchant only works on 32 bit Windows. This may explain why the auto exe installer couldn't see my 64 bit Anaconda distribution...

Comment: @darthbith By the way, thank you for your comments. Incase it appears otherwise; I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: The website that you linked to claims that this Wheel file: https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3.cp27.cp26.cp32.cp33.cp34.pp27/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.6-py2.py3.cp27.cp26.cp32.cp33.cp34.pp27-none-win32.whl contains both the PyEnchant interface as well as the underlying C code. "These pre-built distributions contain a compiled Enchant binary as well as several DLLs produced by Tor Lillqvist." Its possibly a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem.